# Get a List<String> from List<Object> in C#

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a way to extract the Color type as a list from this List?

```
    public List<object1> Color1 = new List<object1>() 
    { new object1{Color=(Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF016864"), Offset=0, Name="Color1"},
      new object1{Color=(Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF01706B"), Offset=20, Name="Color2"},
      new object1{Color=(Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF017873"), Offset=40, Name="Color3"},
      new object1{Color=(Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF018781"), Offset=60, Name="Color4"},
      new object1{Color=(Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF31A7A3"), Offset=80, Name="Color5"}
    };
```

i.e. I want this:

```
public List<string> ColorNames ...
```

I need the string member of my Color1 List, how can I do this?

Comment: Consider renaming your `object1` class.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I renamed my original class to object1 just for the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

LINQ is your friend:

```
List<string> names = Color1.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Or using [`List<T>.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf.aspx):

```
List<string> names = Color1.ConvertAll(x => x.Name);
```

Personally I prefer using LINQ as it then works for non-lists as well, but `ConvertAll` is very slightly more efficient as it knows the size of the destination list from the start.

It's worth learning more about LINQ - it's a *fabulously* useful set of technologies for data transformations. See the [MSDN introduction page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397926.aspx) as a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = Color1.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()
```

Did you mean this list of strings?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> ColorNames = Color1.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

try using a select:

```
public List<string> ColorNames = Color1.Select(c => c.Name).ToList();
```